# How to locate and fill a modal with Protractor?

Tags: protractor, jhipster

I have a website made with JHipster: http://www.jhipsterpress.com/#/post/15/view that I'm trying to test using Protractor (I'm a newbie). So the first thing I would like to test is to login into the site. When you get in, you have to sign in in the modal.

```
  describe('JhipsterPress Demo App', function() {
it('Should login', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.jhipsterpress.com/#/post/15/view');

        element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('admin');
        var username = element(by.binding('username'));
        var password = element(by.binding('password'));
        element(by.css("button[class='btn btn-primary']")).click().then(function(){
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        // Waits max. 5 seconds for the input field to become clickable
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(by.css("button[class='btn btn-primary']")), 5000);
    });
});
```

});

Protractor says...

```
  Message:
    Failed: by.id(...).click is not a function
  Stack:
    TypeError: by.id(...).click is not a function
```

EDIT: And after fixing the parenthesis error:

```
Failures:
1) JhipsterPress Demo App Should login
  Message:
    Failed: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
  Stack:
    ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: Did you enable Protractor tests when generating your app?  That would generate several tests that log in

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because your parentheses are messed up.  You need to close the locator before the `click` function.

Change `element(by.id('login').click())` to `element(by.id('login')).click()`

Comment: Yes, thanks you are right with that too, but still not working. Can you take another look at it, please?

Comment: @Mike You need to open the dropdown before trying to click Login

Answer (score 0):

You're current occurs, because Protractor tries to interact with the input fields of the appearing modal dialog. To solve this you can use [Expected Condition](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions) from `Protractor`.

With them you can wait until the input fields are interact-able:

```
element(by.id('login').click()).then(function(){
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    // Waits max. 5 seconds for the input field to become clickable
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.id('username')), 5000);
    element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('admin');
    ...
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work...let me edit the code with what I'm using..... Message:
    Failed: element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)